# Android: Remove history of child activities in tab group

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabs

I have a tab group with 4 tabs. In 2nd tab i have 4 child activities, after going from child 1 => child 2 => child 3 => child 4 and when i click a button it should return to child 1 as a fresh activity without having the history of child 2 3 4.

i have tried this: starting child 1 from child 4,

```
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(),child1.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    parentActivity.startChildActivity("child", intent);
```

can anyone help me.

Comment: Are you concerned with the size of the activity stack, and memory utilization when cached? Or you just want the parent activity to restart when you close the child activity?

Comment: i just need to restart my parent activity when i close the last child activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your "child" activity with just startActivity, then when back pressed on the child activity, capture onBackPressed on the child activity and start your parent activity again with a new intent like so:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class)
     .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
}
```

This should start you fresh with a newly started parent activity.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesnt work for my requirement coz, i just need to go my child 1 activity on a button click in child 4 activity without having the history of child 2 3 4 after navigating to child 1.

Comment: @Ravitheja Actually my answer does work for that. Change PreviousActivity.Class to whatever your parent activity is on your new Intent instantiation. By overriding onBackPressed() you can decide which activity it goes to when you hit the back button.

Comment: yep..it worked ..thank you so much  @Gary Schreiner
i used the code in onBackPressed of TabActivity

TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
parentActivity.startChildActivity("parentActivity", new Intent(getParent(),ParentActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));